# discordjs this code isn't setting my bot's activity

Tags: discord.js

I would like to know why the code below isn't changing my bot's activity. I run my bot and only the status changes, and the console logs that the bot is online. My bot appears as so: https://gyazo.com/9def3dad8fa388032d9f33b9e3b14de7

Any ideas please?

```
bot.on('ready', ()=>{
    bot.user.setActivity('Chillzone', {type: 'WATCHING'})
    bot.user.setStatus('idle')
    console.log('This bot is online')
});
```

Comment: What do you see when you click on the bot?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/12bd654fb1be52b2f3be3ab714340e51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`I'm ready!`);
  bot.user
    .setPresence({
      activity: { name: 'Chillzone' },
      status: "idle",
      type: "WATCHING"
    })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

It's about the same thing, this worked for me, hope this works for you!

Comment: it worked for the majority, just had to change it up a bit to: https://gyazo.com/29ed1d5ac219fb71a31406c27cc886d7
thank you for opening my eyes!